# How to modify fix coldfusion .cfc file

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

I am not a coldfusion programmer, but I found one line in a CFC file that needs to be changed. and I need help in determining the exact steps to adjust this file which is down C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\cfm, save and recompile and deploy.  Could someone tell me the exact steps.  I just need to change one variable from singular to plural.  How do I do this recompile and get everything running again?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open in text editor.
2. Make change.
3. Save.

ColdFusion is not a compiled language.

The only thing you may also need to do is clear the trusted cache, if its on, which by default, it is not.

To do that, you would log into your servers ColdFusion administrator (http://servername/CFIDE/administrator) go to "Caching" in the left hand menu scroll down and click "Clear Template Cache Now".

Comment: I'd add that it might be a little more complex then that, depending on the application.  If you're using an MVC framework then it may be necessary to reinitialize the app.  Even if not MVC the component still may be cached in a shared scope so, like most times, the answer is 'it depends' on the application in question.  But otherwise, +1 Sean ;)

Comment: True Todd, but there is no way to know, and I doubt the poster could tell us, which framework, or if its no framework, how the CFC was instantiated and if its cached in the app scope, etc.  That said, to the original poster, if the change doesn't immediately take, and you cannot figure out how to simply restart the application (usually a url flag, ?init=1, ?reinit=1, etc) then you can restart the CF service to do the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

you have to execute this script to refresh your web service

```
<cfscript>
// service wsdl file
sdl   =   'http://..../web_service/service_name.cfc?wsdl';
// create object
factory = CreateObject('JAVA', "coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory");
// reference to the XmlRpcService
RpcService = factory.XmlRpcService;
// refresh the object in question
RpcService.refreshWebService(sdl);
</cfscript>
```